# Random Array: string, img, youtube Ionic

Tags: android, ionic3

taught who is approaching ionic, I would like to know how you would do a program that has to pull out of the (string, img, clip from youtube)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did but continues to print the string

```js
export class RandomPage {


  risultato = new Oggetti()
  storico = new Array<Oggetti>()
  lista=new Array()


  constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public storage: Storage, public provaProvider: ProvaProvider) {
    this.createStorico();
    //setInterval(function(){ this.selezionaParola();}.bind(this), 1000);
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad RandomPage');
  }

  createStorico() {

    if (localStorage.getItem("storico") == null) {
      let storico = new Array<Oggetti>()
      localStorage.setItem("storico", JSON.stringify(storico))
    }

    if (localStorage.getItem("lista") == null) {
      let storico = TIPI;
      localStorage.setItem("lista", JSON.stringify(storico))
    }

  }
TIPI = [

  {oggetto:"../assets/imgs/ao (1).jpg", colore: '#E52A00', tipo:'string'},
  {oggetto:"../assets/imgs/ao (2).jpg", colore:'#E52A00', tipo:'string'},
  {oggetto:"../assets/imgs/ao (3).jpg", colore:'#E52A00', tipo:'string'},
  {oggetto:"../assets/imgs/ao (4).jpg", colore:'#E52A00', tipo:'string'},
  {oggetto:"../assets/imgs/ao (5).jpg", colore:'#E52A00', tipo:'string'},
  {oggetto:"../assets/imgs/ao (6).jpg", colore:'#E52A00', tipo:'string'},
  ]



  selezionaParola() {
    this.lista=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lista"))
    console.log(this.lista)
    this.risultato=<Oggetti>this.lista[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.lista.length)]
    this.lista.splice(this.lista.indexOf(this.risultato),1)
    localStorage.setItem("lista", JSON.stringify(this.lista))
    let storic = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("storico"))
    storic.push(this.risultato)
        localStorage.setItem("storico", JSON.stringify(storic))
  }
```

```html
</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
//
  <br>
  <br>
  <button ion-button color="danger" (tap)="selezionaParola()">seleziona parola</button>

  <ion-list style="background-color: {{risultato.colore}}"><a>{{risultato.oggetto}}</a></ion-list>
  <ion-img>{{risultato.oggetto}}</ion-img>


</ion-content>
```